# Reading values from multiple text files with varying information

Tags: python, excel

I am running a software that runs a field solver and dumps the results into a log file. The contents of the text file need not be the same every time. For example:

After the first run, the corresponding log file might contain:

`Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.474 dB
Loss per inch @ 5 GHz = -0.838 dB`

And after the second run, the next corresponding log file might contain:

```
Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.474 dB
Loss per inch @ 5 GHz = -0.838 dB
Loss per inch @ 7.500000e+00 GHz =-0.955 dB
```

My goal is to dump this into an excel file with column names as the LHS of the values in the textfiles and their rows as the RHS for every log file.
I am able to achieve this if the number of entries are the same in the log files using `pandas.DataFrame()`. How do I accomplish this if there has to be a column added dynamically like the above example?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't see, why you would like to have each row in your Textfile as a separate column in the Pandas.Dataframe. Why not make a column called `Loss per Inch` and rows with the index 2.5, 5.0, 7.5... or a second column called frequency with those values, if you prefer, however...

Comment: I mean each row in the text file corresponds to some value. So I thought it would be easier to read if each value had a separate column and the values under it for each text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, I'd recommend reading in all rows as rows of a dataframe, structured in two columns named frequency and loss:

```
df = pd.read_table(_filepath_, sep=' [@GHz=dB ]+', header=None, usecols=[1,2], names=['frequency', 'Loss per inch'], engine='python')

In: df
Out: 
   frequency  Loss per inch
0        2.5         -0.474
1        5.0         -0.838
2        7.5         -0.955
```

Comment: So if I have more values like loss that depend on the frequency, I just add it to names and change usecols = [1,2,3] or whatever number?

Comment: Right, as long as the number of your values does not vary from row to row, you can easily adapt this approach to longer rows with more values.

Comment: So this will be df right? how do i dump it into a csv or excel? just do df.to_csv?

Comment: Yes, just have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id12 - you have a whole lot of options to export pandas dataframes to whatever.

Comment: Alright thanks! If i create a chat, will you be willing to help me with this? Cuz the text file has other things like this that I would like to get clarified.

Comment: Each text file has like loads of variables. So I just wanna know how do you select only what you want like loss per inch in this case

Comment: And I am not getting the frequencies to align under the frequencies column

Comment: No Problem with Chat (if you show me how to do that...) but imho it would be enough if you post one complete row to show the structure and this would be perhaps also interesting for others reading this topic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171066/discussion-between-potato-and-spghttcd).

Comment: I will post the answer in this thread once I get it clarified with you :)

Comment: Hey could you come to the chat? I just have one last query

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas indexing for adding values dynamically into your excel sheet.
Suppose you have documented first iteration values in an excel file.
You read the excel file again and use DataFrame.loc indexing for adding data dynamicallu.

```
import pandas as pd
old1='Loss per inch @ 2.500000e+00 GHz = -0.474 dB'
old2='Loss per inch @ 5 GHz = -0.838 dB'
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[old1.split('@')[0]])
df.loc[len(df)]=old1.split('@')[1]
df.loc[len(df)]=old2.split('@')[1]
df.to_excel('E:/log1.xlsx')
new='Loss per inch @ 7.500000e+00 GHz =-0.955 dB'
splitted=new.split('@')
df=pd.read_excel('E:/log1.xlsx')
print df.head
print df.columns
df.loc[len(df)]=splitted[1]
print df.head
```

Comment: Is there a way where I don't have to mention the string? What if the strings are different everytime?